# How to count duplicate values as one value in sql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a problem regarding of duplicate values in a SQL table column.
I want to make sum of a column values but only count duplicates a once(something like merge them);
something like below:

```
| Items    | value1 | Sub Items    | value2   |
| -------- | ------ |------------- | -------- |
| First    | 50     | First First  | 20       |
| First    | 50     | First Second | 50       |
| Second   | 20     | Second First | 50       |
| Second   | 20     | Second Second| 50       |
| Third    | 30     | Third First  | 50       |
| -------- | ------ |------------- | -------- |
| -------- | 100    |------------- | -------- |
```

I want to sum the values of column(value1) and the total summation must be 100. If I use SUM query it will count duplicates also and the result exceeds 100.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove distinct values in a subquery and then just add them. For example:

```
select sum(n) from (select distinct value1 as n from t) x
```

Comment: I honestly couldn't tell from the way the question was written, but I suspect it probably needs to be `select distinct Items, value1`. There wasn't enough sample data to know one way or the other.

Answer (score 0):

You can use group by Items,value1 which will return only distinct values per Item and the doing the total sum in an outer query :

```
with cte as (
 select Items,value1
 from tbl
 group by Items,value1
) select sum(value1) as tot_distinct_sum
  from cte;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3e932750eace8125e695451900048cba

Written differently for MySQL version older than 8:

```
select sum(value1) as tot_distinct_sum 
from (select Items,
             value1
      from tbl
      group by Items,value1
      ) as t1;
```

Comment: Many thanks Ergest, Is it possible to use it in php query code?

Comment: @HadiMirdamadi yes of course you can

Comment: is it possible to tell me what is t1? is it an alter table(temporary)? and can I use WHERE statement after t1 for specifying the records?

Comment: @HadiMirdamadi t1 is just an alias I used for the subquery, you can name it as you want. you can use where  after the t1 . For example I have excluded 'First' in this example https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d75a30ae221adf34d92a5256608e7ace